# How to display first 20 words on screen then next 20 words through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string within a single tag like the below example, and I want to display the first 20-25 words on screen then next, and so on. When 20 words are displayed then the rest of the text must be hidden.

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Proin sed libero enim sed.</p>
```

So the result that I want is that first display

### Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

Then

### consectetur adipiscing elit

.......

### tincidunt augue interdum.

And when it reaches to end then it restarts from the first sentence again and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far.?

Comment: I just know how to display first 20 letters and then add "Read more" button but I don't want to include click function just want that it displays automatically , like I asked in question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? But is see others are doing your work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```js
const sentence = document.getElementById("sentence");
const words = sentence.innerText.split(" ");

let sentences = [];

words.forEach((word, index) => {
  if ((index + 1) % 20 == 0) sentences.push("\0")
  sentences.push(word)
})

sentences = sentences.join(" ").split(" \0 ")

let index = 0;

sentence.innerText = sentences[index];
index++;

setInterval(() => {
  if (!sentences[index]) index = 0;
  sentence.innerText = sentences[index];
  index++;
}, 1000) // change to whatever you like
```

```html
<p id="sentence">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Proin sed libero enim sed. Cum sociis natoque
  penatibus et. Accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. In massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi
  ipsum faucibus. Platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Commodo
  nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum.</p>
```

I suggest using a smarter algorithm to get the words (splitting by spaces might not always be appropriate)

Answer (score 2):

**Steps:**

1. Take the entire string and split it into an array by `[SPACE]`
2. Divide the array into smaller arrays containing no more than 20 elements each
3. Cycle through those smaller arrays and, each time:

   3.1 join the elements of the smaller array into a single `[SPACE]`-separated string

   3.2 display that string on screen

   3.3 remove that string from the screen

**MDN** is a good javascript reference which will help you build all of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR;

1. Split the sentences into an array of words
2. Extract sub array(20 words)
3. Join the extracted array

#### Logical Process

Assuming the following HTML,

```html
<p id="sentence">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Proin sed libero enim sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et. Accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. In massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus. Platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum.</p>
```

```js
var sentence = document.getElementById("sentence");
var words = sentence.split(" "); // split by a space(words seperator)

var firstTwentyWords = words.slice(0, 20); // create a sub-array of 20 words
var firstTwentyWordsJoined = firstTwentyWords.join(" ");

var nextTwentyWords = words.slice(20, 40); // create a sub-array of 20 words
var nextTwentyWordsJoined = firstTwentyWords.join(" ");

console.log(firstTwentyWordsJoined, nextTwentyWordsJoined); // handle the joined words in your own way.
```

Comment: When 20 words are displayed then rest of text must be hidden.

Comment: try doing `sentence.textContent = firstTwentyWordsJoined` to display first-twenty words only

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by space into an array, loop through the array and append the first 20/25 words as needed

```
if (i > 0 && i % 25 == 0)
    break line "br"
```